# Google chrome console is not showing correct, accurate javascript line number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome, ionic-framework

I am working on an angular project with ionic framework, using ion-router-outlet all that, and trying to debug with google chrome console. But, google chrome console is not showing correct line number and is almost impossible to debug with.

[image]

As you can see, all error now points to main.js:1:anyline. I missed the old time where there are actual accurate bug indicator. How do I fix this issue? Thank you.

Additional information. This is how the source window looks like.
[image]

Also there are this error message after I add break point to the formatted.main.js
[image]

Comment: Your code is minified. Use the unminified dev version for debugging, or generate and use source maps.

Comment: Oh wait I can see it now that I have click the reload button. But then it becomes main.js:formatted:0:anyline. Still impossible to debug for me.

Comment: See my first comment...

Comment: Unfortunately, Turns out my google chrome already tick the enable javascript source map box, it does not helps with the issues...

Comment: It's not only the browser that needs to have source maps enabled. You should also make sure that the sourceMap is enabled in your `angular.json` file and that you are actually using the right build configuration (for example `development`) for which you have enabled source map generation. If you do it correctly, you should be able to see your typescript code in the Source tab, not javascript.

Comment: Hi i have done the configuration and its still main.js:91393 , the configuration is as below,              `` "optimization": true/false(both tried both didn't works),
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false ``

Comment: Since its in "dev" configuration , i serve the angular like this  ``ng serve -c "dev"``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the bug.
Aside from suggestion in comment above such as google chrome console enable "source map option".
Remember to correctly format the angular.json file
For example ,I put the options inside production configuration like this

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
     "fileReplacements": [{
       "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }]
   },
   "optimization": false,
   "sourceMap": true,
   "namedChunks": true,
   "extractLicenses": false,
   "vendorChunk": false,
   "buildOptimizer": false
}
```

And so my `ng serve` command will never make source map.
I shall try something like serve it in production mode with `ng serve --configuration production`.
Or simply put it inside `options`, outside of `production` layer

Sorry didn't gave enough source code, thought my mistake is much more complicated.